# Term for a metric space for which the triangle inequality is strict?

Tags: gn.general-topology, mg.metric-geometry, terminology

Is there a standard term for a metric space in which $\rho(p,r) < \rho(p,q) + \rho(q,r)$ for any distinct $p$, $q$, $r$? Sort of the opposite of [metric convexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_metric_space).

For instance, a subset of euclidean space with the inherited distance function has this property if and only if no three points are colinear. Another example: $\rho^\alpha$ has this property for any metric $\rho$ and any $\alpha \in (0,1)$.

(Context: I'm working on the second edition of my book *Lipschitz Algebras*, and I realized that a property I called "concavity" in the first edition is equivalent to this simple condition.)

Comment: Welp, "concave" it is, then.

Comment: I had to look for this recently: the only reference I found was this paper http://arxiv.org/pdf/1003.5087.pdf, where the property is gracefully called "has no co linear triples of pairwise distinct points".

Comment: @JamesKilbane: thanks! It sounds like there's no standard term, then.

Comment: what about "discollinear"?

Comment: @YCor: I'd be sorely tempted to use that, but my book is already in print ...

Comment: I would call such $\rho$ "strict metric".

Comment: @FedorPetrov: that is the simplest and best answer.

Answer (score 4):

The only thing which I recall in this connection is: Blumenthal in his "Theory and Applications of Distance Geometry" (page 56) calls three points a *linear triple* if the triple is congruent with a triple in $\mathbb{R}^1$. See also page 242 in Blumenthal-Menger, "Studies in Geometry". (Possibly one can find in these books something more relevant, but I do not recall such things now.) So one can call such spaces *without linear triples*.

Comment: Or "linear tripleless"?

Answer (score 2):

*Strictly convex* seems to be the name, at least according to [A Short Course on Banach Space Theory:](https://books.google.nl/books?id=pec4r3EsIiMC)

[image]

Comment: No, this is different. The definition you quote refers to normed spaces and adds a non-colinearity requirement.

Comment: A quick Google search shows that the term "strict convexity" is usually used in the general metric context to mean that for any $p,r$ and any $0 < t < 1$ there is a *unique* $q$ such that $\rho(p,q) = t\rho(p,r)$ and $\rho(q,r) = (1-t)\rho(p,r)$.

Comment: Or it could mean that if $\rho(p,z) = \rho(q,z) > 0$ then $\rho(r,z) < \rho(p,z)$ where $r$ is the *midpoint* of $p$ and $q$ (which would not exist if the triangle inequality were strict). Maybe this is the more common usage. Anyway, very different from what I'm asking.

Comment: I guess the connection is that a normed linear space is strictly convex iff its unit sphere has the strict triangle inequality property.